# How To Fix SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused Laravel Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I try to run the command `php artisan migrate`, an error occurs:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = docker and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - ./cache/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    networks:
      - laravel
```

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST="db"
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=docker
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I try too:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_HOST=localhost
```

thank you very good

Answer (score 0):

In docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    ## -----------------------------------------------
    ##           MySql database
    ## -----------------------------------------------
    mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - db_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      networks:
        - app-network
      deploy:
        mode: global
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"

    php:
      ..
      ..
      environment:
        DB_HOST: mysql
        DB_NAME: db_name
        DB_USERNAME: root
        DB_PASSWORD: root
      networks:
        - laravel

    // map volume
    volumes:
      db_mysql:
```

In MySQL Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:8.0
```

Comment: ERROR: for 788979d5d428_docker_mysql_1  Cannot start service mysql: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:3306 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
ERROR: for mysql  Cannot start service mysql: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:3306 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Answer (score 0):

please chnage the ports in docker-compose.yml File , it works for me
ports:
-  8889:3306

----My->  docker-compose.yml File ---

version: '3.8'

services:

## Web Server Service

nginx:
image: nginx:alpine
container_name: nginx
ports:
- "8080:80"
volumes:
- ./src:/var/www
- ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
depends_on:
- app
- db

#Database Service
db:
image : mysql
container_name : mysql
restart: unless-stopped
tty: true
ports:
-  8889:3306

## volumes:

```
# - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

## environment:

```
 # MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel_blogs
## MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
#  MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: localhost
#  SERVICE_NAME: mysql
#  SERVICE_TAGS: dev
environment:
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE} 
  - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}  
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}  
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD} 
volumes:
   -  ~/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

app:
container_name: app
build:
context: ./php
dockerfile: Dockerfile
volumes:
- ./src:/var/www
ports:
- "9000:9000"
working_dir: /var/www

phpMyAdmin:
#  phpmyadmin:
image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
container_name: phpmyadmin
ports:
- "3400:80"
depends_on:
- db
links:
- db
#pgadmin:
#image: dpage/pgadmin4
#container_name: pgAdmin
#ports:
#  - "5050:80"
#depends_on:
#  - db
#environment:
#  PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: hanieasemi76@gmail.com

## PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password